# Alamofire upload huge file

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I am using Alamofire to upload assets (image/video) as multipart form data. It works fine for file sizes below 300MB (app). When I try to upload a file greater than 300MB, app crashes.

```
if let video = self.avPlayerItem?.asset as? AVURLAsset {
    if let assetData = NSData(contentsOfURL: video.URL) {
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: assetData, name: "file", fileName: "video", mimeType: "video/mp4") // Execution stops here
    }
}
```

I also get the below message from Xcode

[image]

How would I support uploading huge sized videos using Alamofire?

Answer (score 10):

Use Stream to upload instead of converting file to NSData which lead to memory problem and occur crash while uploading huge files. 
sample code

```
  if let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL{
        let assetLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
        assetLibrary.assetForURL(imageUrl , resultBlock: { (asset: ALAsset!) -> Void in
            if let actualAsset = asset as ALAsset? {
                let assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = actualAsset.defaultRepresentation()

                let size = assetRep.size()
                let stream = NSInputStream(URL: assetRep.url())

                Alamofire.upload(
                    .POST,
                    "SERVER_URL",
                    headers: [:],
                    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                         multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(stream: stream!, length: UInt64(size), name: "fileparameter", fileName: "fileName", mimeType: "video/mp4")

                    },
                    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                    let percent = (Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
                                    print(percent)
                                }
                            }
                            upload.validate()
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                print(response);
                            }
                        case .Failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                            let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 404, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Image Uploading Failed. Please try again."])
                            let result = Result<AnyObject, NSError>.Failure(error)
                            let response = Response(request: nil, response: nil, data: nil, result: result)
                             print(response);

                        }
                    }
                )

            }
            }, failureBlock: { (error) -> Void in
        })
    }
```

Comment: Actually what happens here if upload fails and how re-upload should be done? Sorry if I go out of the scope of a question/answer, but I wonder, by going this way, are we going to have to upload a whole video file again, or only its certain part/chunk (and how) ?

Comment: @Whirlwind for that you have to set delegate of Stream and when delegate event get error you need to Suspend your HttpTask. So that you could again resume that Http Task from pending upload.

Answer (score 2):

[Alamofire Documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data)

> Uploading Data to a Server
>   When sending relatively small amounts of data to a server using JSON or URL encoded parameters, the request() APIs are usually sufficient. If you need to send much larger amounts of data from Data in memory, a file URL, or an InputStream, then the upload() APIs are what you want to use.
>
> Uploading Data
>
> ```
> let data = Data("data".utf8)
>
> AF.upload(data, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
>     debugPrint(response)
> }
> ```
>
> Uploading a File
>
> ```
> let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")
>
> AF.upload(fileURL, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
>     debugPrint(response)
> }
> ```
>
> Uploading Multipart Form Data
>
> ```
> AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
>     multipartFormData.append(Data("one".utf8), withName: "one")
>     multipartFormData.append(Data("two".utf8), withName: "two")
> }, to: "https://httpbin.org/post")
>     .responseJSON { response in
>         debugPrint(response)
>     }
> ```
>
> Upload Progress While your user is waiting for their upload to
>   complete, sometimes it can be handy to show the progress of the upload
>   to the user. Any UploadRequest can report both upload progress of the
>   upload and download progress of the response data download using the
>   uploadProgress and downloadProgress APIs.
>
> ```
> let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")
>
> AF.upload(fileURL, to: "https://httpbin.org/post")
>     .uploadProgress { progress in
>         print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
>     }
>     .downloadProgress { progress in
>         print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
>     }
>     .responseJSON { response in
>         debugPrint(response)
>     }
> ```