# Alamofire Swift: upload more than 10mb file?

Tags: php, swift, parameters, upload, alamofire

I'm making a social application with the ability to post and attach images & videos.

I've noticed that if I try to upload heavy files then the PHP will not get some parameters (`userId` and `session` for example).

**Alamofire allows only 10mb of file being uploaded without a stream.**

My question is, how could I rewrite this code to be able to upload more images / videos at the same time heavier than 10mb overall?

**Here's the code for the posting:**

```
func post(message: String, type: Int, duration: Int, pickedFiles: [Any], completion: @escaping (ActionResult?, Int?, String?, Int?, Int?, String?)->()){

        var pickedVideoUrls : [URL] = []
        var pickedImages : [UIImage] = []
        for file in pickedFiles {
            if let image = file as? UIImage {
                pickedImages.append(image)
            } else if let videoUrl = file as? URL {
                pickedVideoUrls.append(videoUrl)
            }
        }
        let userId = UserData.shared.details.userId
        let session = UserData.shared.details.session

        if (latitude == nil || longitude == nil){
            return completion(ActionResult(type: 0, title: NSLocalizedString("error", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("err_locServicesFail", comment: "")), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil)
        }

        let connectUrl = URL(string: appSettings.url + "/src/main/post.php")



        Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append("\(userId)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "userId")
            multipartFormData.append(session.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "session")
             multipartFormData.append(message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!, withName: "message")
             multipartFormData.append("\(type)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "type")
             multipartFormData.append("\(duration)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "duration")

            // Now upload the videos & images
            var fileNumber = 0
            for file in pickedFiles {
                if let image = file as? UIImage {
                    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)!
                    multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image[]", fileName: "file.\(fileNumber).png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    fileNumber+=1
                } else if let videoUrl = file as? URL {
                    multipartFormData.append(videoUrl, withName: "video[]", fileName: "file.\(fileNumber).mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
                    fileNumber+=1
                }
            }



        }, to: connectUrl!, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    // EVERYTHING WAS FINE
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):

                // ERROR
            }
        })
    }
```

If I upload small files <10mb it works fine.

**UPDATE 1**

It is because of the Alamofire size limit:

MAhipal Singh suggested that with a Stream it could be solved: [Alamofire upload huge file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398201/alamofire-upload-huge-file)

But I don't really understand it..

Comment: can your PHP accept large size uploads, the problem might be in the php side not iOS

Comment: @Tobi yes, the PHP is able to handle files up to 25MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing error codes it’s hard to tell , however I’m sure the limitation is in your php setup, check your`php.ini` for upload max file size and perhaps post max size values. You’ll find out it’s most probably 10 mb.

Bumping that up to a higher value will work, but I suggest you do more research on how that will affect your server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is with Alamofire: it has problem with files over 10MB. Some other user answered a Stream might fix that problem. Updated the post.

Comment: Do you have a reference about the 10mb limitation on alamofire? I don’t see that anywhere

Comment: I assume there is, I have no reference. I’ve tried uploading 9.5mb of data and everything was fine, but if it’s more than 10mb then my PHP will not recieve the whole data, for example the userId and Session gets lost. It’s more like a memory management issue with Alamofire that when it tries to create NSData out of a file it gets lost. Reference to the user mentioned in my updated post

Comment: Without getting error codes or crashes ? then it's most probably a wrong assumption, if it's memory related you'll surely get a crash.

what happens if you upload just one file, that's bigger than 10 mb ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or crashes. In that case if I upload one file larger than 10mb it is the same: the PHP won't get anything, even though the alamofire succeeds uploading the data.

Comment: I’m 100% sure it’s your php script and setup that’s causing that, Alamofire has nothing to do with what you’re seeing. Past the contents of your ‘php.ini’ that are related too upload max size and post max size.

Comment: You was right, thank you! I had to change the .htaccess file to match the php.ini! But now it's fine!

Comment: @AndrasKarpati awesome ! Congratulations that it works :) good luck with the rest of your work 